# Create a Pull request in bitbucket using Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am interested in creating a pull request on bitbucket using jenkins pipeline job based on groovy. I am creating a jenkins job which is pulling the code then doing some changes and then pushing the code to bitbucket and then I want to raise PullRequest.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for the same, unfortunately I only find a way to do this using the bitbucket rest apis.
It would be nice to have a plugin to do this, but I could not find it.

This is the rest api
https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.6.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp291

/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests

There are more details here
[How to create a pull request in a Bitbucket using api 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310751/how-to-create-a-pull-request-in-a-bitbucket-using-api-1-0)